# Securing method access to a specific assembly

Tags: .net

We're in .net 3.5. I would like to secure certain methods (or classes) in one assembly so that only another specific assembly can access it. Lets call them *consumer* and *provider*

One way I know is by using `StrongNameIdentityPermissionAttribute`. Problem is that we don't sign our assemblies. Signing it will make all hell break loose.

Another way - is in code by using `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName`. And verify name to match. With this, I have to code in each method, at least a call to a reusable method. Ok.

And of course there is `InternalsVisibleTo` but this is not what we want to be based on.

Is there another way how to implement something like this on the class level, or method level, preferably attribute-based? I mean by existing framework capability. I can develop my custom attributes - no doubt

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to use the GetCallingAssembly method you mention above in conjunction with [Windsor Castle Proxy](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-interceptors-and-proxyoptions.md) with an interceptor. You would mark your methods with an attribute, leave the classes as internal and expose construction via a factory which handles the proxy and interceptor (this does require you to make internals visible to DynamicProxyGenAssembly2). Consumer of your code doesn't need to do anything special and it will throw when called. Its a runtime error, which isn't great but it does what you need.

The rough implementation would look something like this:

```
 [TestFixture]
public class Foo
{
    [Test]
    public void Should_throw()
    {
        var nonProxyService = new Service();
        nonProxyService.MethodWithSpecialPermissions().Should().BeTrue();
        var interceptor = new PermissionInterceptor();
        var generator = new ProxyGenerator();
        var proxyService = (IService)generator.CreateClassProxy(
                typeof(Service), new Type[] { typeof(IService) }, new IInterceptor[] { interceptor });
        Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => proxyService.MethodWithSpecialPermissions());
    }
}

public interface IService
{
    [SpecialPermissionAttribute]
    bool MethodWithSpecialPermissions();
}

public class SpecialPermissionAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class Service : IService
{

    public bool MethodWithSpecialPermissions()
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class PermissionInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        if (invocation.Method.HasAttribute<SpecialPermissionAttribute>()
            && Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName != "foo")
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
```

I placed the Attribute on the Interface since it seemed reasonable to communicate to callers that its a weird method, but it could probably be moved to the implementation with a little bit of work.

Comment: I appreciate your time. But I think, this is unnecessary complex. In my situation, I need to protect some classes from access by all but one assembly. Ok, may be 2 -unit test too. I can create a base class with constructor that calls `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().FullName` and throw exception "you're not allowed to use this class". We're not targeting protection from hackers, this is against consultant/developer direct access. Best would be deny class visibility at design time altogether.

Comment: Completely understandable. Proxies are a fair bit of complexity. As far as I know there is no way to deny visibility at compile time except InternalsVisibleTo, this is a limit of the language. Public is all or nothing.

That said, if you want an AoP solution using attributes Castle Dynamic Proxy is a pretty standard solution (used by lots of libraries, nhibernate for example.) Otherwise the base class solution does work well. Another option is an injected dependency that does the Calling Assembly validation (from the Composition over Inheritance school of thought).

Comment: +1 for good try. Injected dependency will probably not work because than, consumer can send his own "dependency handler". But that is exactly what I don't want. We want to enforce the specific rule. One thing we can do is establish list of allowed assemblies in the common  vertical assembly that is not touched by consultants and do the checking in the base.